# Where do I set the script MODE

Tags: spring-boot

I want to create an `init.d` service for my spring-boot app.

I want it to be stopped by default and only run when the user runs `service my-app start`.

Where do I set `MODE=service` as described on below page.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Answer (score 0):

Found I needed to add the `embeddedLaunchScriptProperties` option to the Spring Boot Maven